# Limit of function (definition)

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Consider the following error at the definition of limit:

$ \forall \epsilon > 0 \; \exists \delta > 0; x \in X, 0 < |x-a| < \epsilon \Rightarrow |f(x) - L| < \delta $

Show that f satifies this condition if, and only if, this function is bounded in every bounded interval of center $a$. In the affirmative case, L can be every real number.

---

I already showed the first implication. I have doubts about the second one.

**My attempt:**

Suppose that $f$ is bounded in every interval of center $a$. That is, given an $\epsilon > 0$ and $x \in X $($X$ is the domain), if $x \in ( - \epsilon + a, \epsilon + a)$, then $ \exists M \geq 0 ; |f(x)| \leq M$

I've tried to find my $L$ using every $M$ for all my $\epsilon$'s. That is, consider the set

$S=${$M \in \mathbb{R}: \exists \epsilon > 0 ; |x-a| < \epsilon \Rightarrow |f(x)| \leq M $} (maybe the definition os not clear, but take all the limitants for every $\epsilon$). Using $infS$ (S is bounded and is not empty), I've tried to find my $L$

But I am not sure that it is correct. First because I know my infimum is not less than 0, and it is not clear that my $L$ can not be negative. I do 't know if i am on the right way, it doesn't look correct.

Thanks for your attention!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you might be confusing the order in which things are picked and things are given. You pick $\epsilon >0$, and then you immediately get a $\delta(\epsilon) > 0$ (or, in your case, an $M(\epsilon) > 0$). Now, if you decide to pick an $x \in X$ with $0 < | x - a| < \epsilon$, you know that $|f(x) - L| < M$. Also, you don't need to find a *uniform* bound, just one on each interval.

The proof is straightforward once you understand what this is saying:

$(\Rightarrow)$ If you have an interval centered at $a$, say $(a - \epsilon, a + \epsilon)$, and you pick an $x$ in this interval, then either $x = a$ in which case $f(x) = f(a)$, or by the above, $|f(x) - L| < M$ (or, equivalently, $-M < f(x) - L < M$). So, in either case, we have $f(x)$ is bounded below by $\min(-M + L, f(a))$ and above by $\max(M + L, f(a))$.

If you still have trouble with the second implication, you can mouseover below for the proof:

> $(\Leftarrow)$ Conversely, if $f$ is bounded in every interval centered at $a$, then given $\epsilon > 0$, we can consider $f$ on the interval $(a - \epsilon, a+ \epsilon)$. This is an interval centered at $a$, so $f$ is bounded on it, say $A < f(x) < B$ for all $x \in (a - \epsilon, a + \epsilon)$. Define $M = \max(|A - L|, |B - L|)$ (and observe that this is nonzero). Then, clearly, $|f(x) - L| < M$ for all $x \in (a - \epsilon, a + \epsilon)$, and in particular for all $x$ so that $0 < | x- a| < \epsilon$.

Comment: Thank you very much! I did the first one, but thank you too